# Получение ядра linux из прошивки

Tags: linux, прошивка

Путем определенных манипуляций удалось получить из прошивки роутера файловую систему и [часть](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-a0P5mTc4nySbn3UjrT-iRwFYKK3am1M/view) которая по моему мнению содержит ядро linux.По поводу части содержащей ядро, binwalk показывает следующее:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как мне из нее извлеч ядро? Как я понимаю binwalk использует эврестический анализ , поэтому данные которые я получил с его помощью могут быть неверными.  Попытки извлеч  binwalk -e ./98.bin   заканчиваються получением поврежденных файлов.

Как мне известно, ядро linux упаковываеться в gzip и  упакованный код начинаеться с "магической полседовательности" 1F 8B 08 00(ее я могу найти по адрису 27DFD0). т.е по идее я должен вырезать фрагмент данных начиная от 27DFD0 и заканчивая..... чем? чтобы распаковать это gzip...

Comment: от указанного места и до конца файла. А потом попробовать распаковать. И либо распакует (и будет файл), или ругнется (и тогда будет понятно, где отрезать)

Comment: А что вам с этого ядра то? Ну достаните вы файлик gz, ну получите ядро + доработки вендора, уже собранные. В чем польза? Возможно конечную задачу надо решать не расковыриванием собранных бинарных прошивок, а более научно

Comment: Почему не добавили   опцию -M при распаковке?  То есть, вот так должно быть:    binwalk -e -M  ./98.bin

Comment: Из мана :-M, --matryoshka
              Recursively scan extracted files

Comment: "от указанного места и до конца файла"- он распаковывает только малую часть, все остальное теряеться.

Comment: "решать не расковыриванием собранных бинарных прошивок, а более научно" -мне нужно ядро закинуть в дизасемблер и коечто посмотреть... как это сделать более научно , без снятия паковки я незнаю, может подскажите?

Comment: binwalk -e -M ./98.bin  - получаю аналогичный результат

Comment: Ядро Linux распространяется по условиям соглашения GPL v2. В чём проблема посмотреть в исходники?

Comment: мне нужно  ядро с прошивки, а не "левые"